# Issue in Toast message parameter in Android

Tags: android

I want to display a toast message in a static class but the is an issue of Toast message parameter passing context of application. Pleas help me, how to display the toast message in static class. Please recommend me the change that I have need to do, I will be very thankful to you. Here is a portion of my code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.training_four_position);
            mEndlessRunnable = (Runnable) new UpdateRunnable();
            mEndlessRunnable.run();
    }


   private static class UpdateRunnable implements Runnable  {
   private int mState; 

   public UpdateRunnable(Handler handler, Button[] buttons) {
         mHandler = handler;
         mButtons = buttons;
   }

    public void run() {
        switch (mState) {
        case 0:
               mState = 1;
               break;
        case 1:

            mState = 0;
               // Here is the issue in my toast message
               Toast.makeText(CONTEXT, "Toast message.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
     }

  mHandler.postDelayed(this,1000)); 

  }// End of run()
  }//End of class UpdateRunnable
  } //End of MainActivity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to make a separate method for your toast

```
public void showToast(String message){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}//end showToast
```

and then call that in your inner class.

Comment: lol... if this function is in the scope of activity then it should be static so that inner class can access it and then you can't use getApplicationContext() in a static function... If its in the static inner class then again same issue, u can't use getApplicationContext in static inner class..

Comment: aha ok ... :/
How about also extending your inner class with the Activity class and then adding the context in your constructor?
mEndlessRunnable = (Runnable) new UpdateRunnable(MainActivity.this);

Comment: if you are adding context in constructor then extending with Activity is of no use...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your Activity's Context to your UpdateRunnable class in constructor and use it then in your run() function.

However if you are showing Toast from an inner class then that inner class, probably, shouldn't be a static class at all. You can remove static keyword and use your Activity's getContext() in run() then.

Why do you want your inner class static?

Comment: @Farhan Not really in this case because this class is going to use a particular Context anyway thus have a dependency on its outer class

Comment: yeah i was just saying that normally its good... sometimes you make an object like textview and other stuff in inner class... i dont know the details but as i said i read somewhere... :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the way is to use a static variable in your activity.

public static Context myContext;

then update it in onCreate..

```
onCreate()
{
    myContext = getApplicationContext();
}
```

Other way is to pass the context in the constructor of your class...

Answer (score 0):

I guess getParent() or getApplicationContext() should do the work pass the parameter to the class and have a local context object .Let me know if it fails